# Use Jquery/Ajax to Load A Page Within A Page, Without Refreshing

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I would like to use a DIV to load a page within a page. Seems simple enough - BUT, I would like to do this WITHOUT refreshing the entire page.

Here is my example:

`browse.php` --> Lists all of the items that I currently have for sale on my site. This page can be incredibly long, and taxing to reload (especially on slower connections).

`editcart.php` --> This is the page that I would like to load within browse.php. It allows the user to add/remove a specific item from their cart.

Is there any way that I can load `editcart.php` on `browse.php` WITHOUT refreshing `browse.php`?

Comment: Yes, you'd load it either with a button click, or some other event. This is exactly what AJAX is for. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried several things from tutorials or other Stackoverflow.com questions. This script almost did what I wanted it to do:

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('div#edit_cart').load("editcart.php");
    });
    </script>

It loads the new page, but it still reloads browse.php when a user makes changes to their cart via the DIV containing editcart.php

Comment: @user1484106 - Um... `.load` will not refresh any pages. Also you might want to use `$.ajax` which has more controls.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Sorry, if I have almost no experience with scripts of this nature. The thing is, there are post submit buttons and links within editcart.php. So, when they choose those options.. it refreshes both browse.php AND editcart.php. If I just wanted to include another page, I could have used the PHP include function. But, that's not what I want to do. If I'm not being clear enough, please let me know and I will try to explain my problem better! Thank you!

Comment: It's like you don't want the page to refresh when the user click Save in the DIV? If that's true, your question wasn't that clear. As @derek said, `.load()` is Ajax, it won't refresh the page

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted to do, tcoder. Sorry if I wasn't being clear. Is there a way I can do this? Or any suggestions as to how I can improve this post? Thank you.

Comment: Isn't this exactly what iframes were invented for?

Answer (score 3):

If it's just loading the page you can do the following using the `.load()` method

That was the first item that came up in google search

```
 $('.editableItem').click(function(){
    $('#editDiv').load('editcart.php');
 });
```

You can [read more about this and other methods here](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: I tried that script, but it did not fit my needs completely. You see, editcart.php has post submit buttons within it. I need a script (or tutorial to help me) that will not only include editcart.php, but that will make it so that when a user ..let's say.. adds "Item1" to their cart, it will not refresh the entire browse.php page - it will only refresh editcart.php and the DIV containing it.

Comment: @Connie - I don't understand where is problem. `editcart.php` is never opened, so how is it *refreshed*?? Actually you can learn more on AJAX [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Ajax).

Comment: I understand what he wants now. It's in my comment up there. He just want to able to interact with editcart.php links and buttons inside the DIV without refreshing the page. I think he needs another $.ajax in editcart.php

Comment: @Derek - I guess, it doesn't technically get refreshed. I'm just not all that good at this. The page reloads and makes the appropriate MySQL changes when a user makes changes to the specific item.

Comment: Hey everyone! Thanks for all of your help! I tried Googling my problem a different way, and came up with this solution that works for my purposes: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/ueucL/6/)